# Position of holes on a floorball ball?

Tags: rules, equipment, floorball

I'm not a floorball player, I'm a mathematician. I got recently curious about the floorball ball: it's got 26 holes, which is an unusual number, and I wondered how they are placed on the ball.

It seems there is no regulation for this, certainly it's not in [IFF Material Regulations (2016)](http://www.floorball.org/pages/EN/Material-Regulations) document. There is some drawing in the appendix, but still, the placement seems to only have some general rules (like minimal distance between holes).

Is it really true that the balls do not have a predefined shape? And if so, what is the most common placement of the holes?

Comment: Not sure as to the "why" but on a sphere we have 1 hole at each end, then a row of 4 holes and then a 2 rows of 8 holes, followed by another row of 4 holes. Totalling 26. Seems logical to have 1,4,8,8,4,1 configuration but that does not mean why other slight variations are not considered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that ball have no predetermined shape. And the distribution of the holes of the ball is usually made following the design represented in SP document [MATERIAL REGULATIONS](http://www.floorball.org/Liitetiedostot/en120605.pdf), which divides the ball in two equal halves, later joined to position a hole between two holes above the joint,

[image: Position of the holes above the joint from SP Technical Research Institute of Sweden]

For a more even distribution of holes, during design process the ball was divided into eight sections for symmetry. As each section should have the same number of holes, it leads to 3.25 holes that can be differently distributed. For the possibility of creating a seamless ball, the holes can be distributed along every direction as shown in figure.

[image: figure]

From [*Development of the Floorball*](http://publications.lib.chalmers.se/records/fulltext/241131/241131.pdf) by Sara Mateos Fernández.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, you write "usually" at the very beginning. So you confirm that there is no hard rule on this?

Comment: @yo' Usually balls are made from the first figure but now other method shown in second fig is also used for more even distribution. Thanks sir for reading all and letting me know.

Comment: @Nij sir thanks for editing, still don't know how to reference copyrighted material. Sometime referencing too much while sometime not enough to prevent downvote.

Comment: Reading the TOU under the "legal" link on any page is probably a useful thing, and asking about how copyrighted material on Stack Exchange work would be a good question on Law SE.